# wp_get_post_categories - can I get related posts for a specific category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get a set of posts from a specific category. Here is my situation:

I have a portfolio web site I am building and on a project post I want to display the different capabilities used on the project. Capabilities such as design, strategy etc. I have created a custom post type called capabilities and created each capability there. I have also created a category for each capability.

How can I construct a custom query to get only the capabilities posts that are used by the project post? I can get all of the categories used in the post, but I need just the 'capabilities' category.

Comment: I think you should create `capabilities` as a taxonomy, not a post type, then you can use `tax_query` in `WP_Query`

Comment: Apart from the first fine comment, there is documentation you should use: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query - probably in your case the *Type Parameters* combined with the *Category Parameters*